# Когда следует оставить только nginx?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Неоднократно слышал о конфигурациях веб-серверов когда apache вообще не применяют и используют только nginx в качестве вебсервера. Вопросы которые в связи с этим возникают:

1. Причины такого решения?
2. Выгоды?
3. Какие есть подводные камни у такого решения? Например многие панели управления с апачем вроде работают, а VestaCP при установке вообще ставится вместе с апачем и mysql-сервером. Выходит что такие панельки уже не получится применять, или в них в этом случае нет необходимости?

Answer (score 5):

Есть такие конфигурации.

1. Отпадает необходимость в настройке Apache
2. Меньшее количество сущностей, которыми нужно заниматься на сервере (см. пункт 1). За счет отсутствия дополнительной прокладки в виде Apache возможно незначительное уменьшение времени отдачи результатов запроса клиенту
3. Не вижу необходимости в наличии панели на сервере вообще, поскольку любая панель - потенциальная дыра в безопасности и некоторое дополнительное потребление ресурсов сервера. Конфиги того, что можно установить и настроить через панель не настолько сложны, чтобы их  не научиться писать самому. (Примеров таких конфигов в сети достаточно, а MySQL ставится элементарно.) Хотя, согласен, панель может упростить работу с сервером.

Все вышеизложенное сугубо мое мнение. На истину в последней инстанции не претендую. (Вопрос использования\неиспользования Apache или Nginx чреват серьезными холиварами, при которых каждый остается при своем).

Comment: Спасибо. Весьма понятный ответ. Меня по крайне мере он натолкнул на размышления и позволил сделать некоторые выводы.

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, следует задаваться вопросом - зачем вообще на сервере нужен Apache? nginx зачастую имеет делать все то же самое.

Админ-панели - это вообще не подводные камни. Надо просто выбирать и ставить ту, которая nginx поддерживает. Кроме того, надо понимать: админ-панель - вещь вообще-то необязательная, если вы смогли поставить и настроить nginx - сможете и сайт на нем поднять.

Действительно подводный камень есть только один. Многие CMS или фреймворки содержат "изкоробочный" файл .htaccess, который является частью системы конфигурации Apache. Если вы будете поднимать такой продукт на nginx - вам, скорее всего, понадобится все настройки из этого файла переписать в конфиг nginx. Сделать это правильно - та еще задача, потому и ставят Apache.

Answer (score -1):

"На вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные".
Мои любимые "фломастеры": debian, centos, nginx, postgresql .
Из личного опыта:

1. Установил и настроил zabbix 3.2.1 на несколько серверов. Использовались: nginx, php(5)-fpm, postgresql ; НЕ использовались: apache, mysql . Проблем не наблюдаю.
2. Установил и настроил owncloud 9 на пару серверов, также - только nginx, php(5)-fpm, postgresql. Несколько месяцев назад начал "переползать" на nextcloud 10. В nextcloud 10 НЕ смог настроить Collabora Online на nginx. Причина - nginx не смог проксировать web socket запросы, по крайней мере в стандартной комплектации. На "допиливание" nginx времени не было. Установил для этого apache, только для Collabora Online. Основной frontend - nginx.